# How mongorestore DB with docker

Tags: mongodb, docker, mongorestore

I got that docker-compose.yml:

```
version: '2'
services:
  web:
    build: .
    ports:
     - "3000:3000"
    volumes:
     - .:/code
    depends_on:
     - db1
    links:
     - db1:mongo
  db1:
    image: mongo
```

Dockerfile:

```
FROM node:4.4.2
ADD . /code
WORKDIR /code
RUN npm i
CMD node app.js
```

I store dump in project files so folder is shared with container. How should look like proccess of restoring dump ? In web container I don't have access to mongoresore commnad ...